# Generating XML using T-SQL and some issues

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xml-namespaces

I'm using your knowledge for some time, but this time I didn't find answer for my question. 
I'm self-taught, so forgive me any mistakes.

I need to generate XML, I have never done that using SQL, so I have some issues.
I have generated core, but I need to add schema and version and I'm not able to make it.

I have prepared a quick sample, it has to be same architecture.
How it looks now:

```
  <s:headers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="http://www.example.com">
      <warehouse_iss type="T">
        <idn>wareh</idn>
      </warehouse_iss>
      <iss_id type="T">
        <id>1</id>
      </iss_id>
      <date>2018-10-15T21:48:36.220</date>
      <items xmlns:s="http://www.example.com">
        <prod_index type="T">
          <idn>abc</idn>
        </prod_index>
        <qty>1.230000000000000e+002</qty>
        <parameters xmlns:s="http://www.example.com">
          <parameter>
            <par_id type="T">
              <id>1</id>
            </par_id>
            <par_value type="T">
              <id>abcdef</id>
            </par_value>
          </parameter>
        </parameters>
      </items>
    </s:headers>
```

How it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:headers xmlns:s="http://www.example.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/example ../../Schema/example.xsd ">
  <warehouse_iss type="T">
    <idn>wareh</idn>
  </warehouse_iss>
  <iss_id type="T">
    <id>1</id>
  </iss_id>
  <date>2018-10-15T21:48:36.220</date>
  <items>
    <prod_index type="T">
      <idn>abc</idn>
    </prod_index>
    <qty>1.230000000000000e+002</qty>
    <parameters>
      <parameter>
        <par_id type="T">
          <id>1</id>
        </par_id>
        <par_value type="T">
          <id>abcdef</id>
        </par_value>
      </parameter>
    </parameters>
  </items>
</s:headers>
```

So I need to add all schemas and elements and it should not be repeted in child nodes. 
I also need to add version.

Code I've prepared to help you help me (MyFunction is of course function which adds "@type" to output XML) 
;)

```
create table #temp_headers (warehouse_iss varchar(5), iss_id int, date datetime)
create table #temp_items (prod_index varchar(10), qty float)
create table #temp_parameter (par_id int,  par_value varchar(10), prod_index varchar(10))
insert into #temp_headers values ('wareh',1,getdate())
insert into #temp_items  values ('abc',123)
insert into #temp_parameter values (1, 'abcdef','abc')


WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.example.com' as s)
select 
                                dbo.MyFunction(1,'T') as "warehouse_iss/@type", 
                                warehouse_iss as "warehouse_iss/idn",
                                dbo.MyFunction(1,'T') as "iss_id/@type", 
                                iss_id as "iss_id/id", --- iss_id
                                GETDATE() date, --- date
                                    (select 
                                        dbo.MyFunction(1,'T') as "prod_index/@type", 
                                        prod_index as "prod_index/idn", 
                                        qty,
                                        (select 
                                        dbo.MyFunction(1,'T') as "par_id/@type", 
                                        par_id as "par_id/id", 
                                        dbo.MyFunction(1,'T') as "par_value/@type", 
                                        par_value as "par_value/id"
                                        from #temp_parameter para                                       
                                        where para.prod_index = items.prod_index
                                        FOR XML PATH ('parameter'), ROOT ('parameters'), type
                                        )
                                        from #temp_items items
                                        for xml path ('items'), type
                                        )
                                from #temp_headers head

                                for xml path ('s:headers'),     ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very annoying issue, known for a decade, but Microsoft is not willing to change it. Namespaces are repeated in sub-queries over and over. Search for this and you will find hundreds of questions about this. There was a connect-issue for more than ten years with a lot of supporters, but connect is gone and the issue is gone - but the namespaces remain...

Btw: Your query is great!

However, the solution is possible, but it is ugly. You have to create your XML without namespaces and add them on string level at the end:

```sql
create table #temp_headers (warehouse_iss varchar(5), iss_id int, date datetime)
create table #temp_items (prod_index varchar(10), qty float)
create table #temp_parameter (par_id int,  par_value varchar(10), prod_index varchar(10))
insert into #temp_headers values ('wareh',1,getdate())
insert into #temp_items  values ('abc',123)
insert into #temp_parameter values (1, 'abcdef','abc');
```

-- thx for the test scenario!

```sql
DECLARE @intermediateXML XML=
(
    select 
        'Dummy T' as "warehouse_iss/@type", 
        warehouse_iss as "warehouse_iss/idn",
        'Dummy T' as "iss_id/@type", 
        iss_id as "iss_id/id", --- iss_id
        GETDATE() date, --- date
            (select 
                'Dummy T' as "prod_index/@type", 
                prod_index as "prod_index/idn", 
                qty,
                (select 
                'Dummy T' as "par_id/@type", 
                par_id as "par_id/id", 
                'Dummy T' as "par_value/@type", 
                par_value as "par_value/id"
                from #temp_parameter para                                       
                where para.prod_index = items.prod_index
                FOR XML PATH ('parameter'), ROOT ('parameters'), type
                )
                from #temp_items items
                for xml path ('items'), type
                )
        from #temp_headers head

        for xml path ('DummyHeaders') 
);
```

--cast it to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`...

```sql
DECLARE @XML_as_String NVARCHAR(MAX)=CAST(@intermediateXML AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

--... and add the header on string level with string methods

```sql
DECLARE @Header NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'<s:headers xmlns:s="http://www.example.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/example ../../Schema/example.xsd ">';

DECLARE @finalXML XML=
(
    REPLACE(
        (SELECT @Header + 
           (
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@XML_as_String,CHARINDEX(N'<warehouse_iss',@XML_as_String),LEN(@XML_as_String))
           )
        ),'</DummyHeaders>','</s:headers>')
);

SELECT @finalXML

GO
DROP TABLE #temp_headers
DROP TABLE #temp_items
DROP TABLE #temp_parameter
```

### Hint: One remark about the *xml-declaration* `<?xml blah?>`

Your XML is encoded as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` by default (which is `UCS-2`, almost `utf-16)`. If you add a declaration telling a consumer *Hey, I'm `utf-8`!*, this is not the truth. This declaration is not meant as a part of the XML, but as something *in advance*, telling a consumer how to decode the content. SQL-Server will not even allow you to store this as native XML.

But - of course - you can add any string to a string. So you can add your declaration to the casted XML (but don't cast it back to XML!). If you write this out to a file on the disc, you should be sure, that this file is `utf-8` encoded actually. Otherwise your file would be a liar ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Shnugo! I tried it exactly that way, but I suppose received XML parsing error, so I done something wrong.

Now it's working and you're completly right - it's UTF-16 :)

Comment: @Kris_S, It works with your sample data, doesn't it? Try to print out the created XML as a string and find out, where the XML is invalid... There are *online xml validators* to do this, [here's one](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/?L=2), but there are many more to find...

Comment: It works with my target query. All I'm saying that my very similar solution was unperfect, so it wasn't working. 
Your solution works fine, so thanks again. 

PS. I'm very pleased that my query isn't bad :)